# Laptop sometimes won't come out of sleep mode since updating to 21.04

Tags: suspend, 21.04

This is on an ROG Zephyrus M15. I updated Ubuntu to 21.04 a couple days ago, and since then there's been three times when I try to get it out of sleep mode it won't do it. I have to hold the power button until it turns off then start the computer again. I'm pretty sure it's related to the update since it didn't happen before it, but it's happened three times in just a couple days. If anyone has any advice that could help prevent this I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem with the laptop Acer Predator. Should I change and check video driver?

Comment: I'm trying an older NVIDIA driver per comments on the post BeastOfCaerbannog linked. If this doesn't solve the problem I'll comment again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem with the laptop Acer Predator. I opened "NVIDIA X Server settings" and changed the NVidia to Intel (Power saving mode).

Comment: Wouldn't switching to Intel mode effectively mean turning off the NVIDIA card and using the integrated one?